# Is there a way to download an entire Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, download

Is there a way to download an entire Facebook page to read it offline?

I would like to read posts from particular Facebook page from the oldest to the newest - to do that I would need to scroll to the bottom of the page which in case of pages that have been posting for years it's impossible. My next thought was to download the entire page, but is it possible?

EDIT: scrolling down the page even when using the END key does not work - because there is so much content the browser finally gives up and crashes - even I have a good specs mac

Answer (score 4):

Facebook only loads the page a section at a time.  If you were to look at the HTML when you first load the page, it only includes what you see.  After you scroll to the bottom, and more of the page loads, then more HTML gets added. So if you try to download when the page first loads, you'll only get what's visible.

Here's a solution:

- Open the Facebook page in your web browser
- Press the "End" key to jump to the bottom
- Facebook will load more of the page
- Press the "End" key again
- More of the page loads
- Keep doing that until you reach the end
- Then press Ctrl-S or Cmd-S to make your web browser save the page

That should save the entire page on your computer.  It will comprise one main HTML file and a lot of other files (like pictures) in a folder.  You can open the HTML file when you're offline, and you should be able to see the whole Facebook page.

Comment: or if it's going to take you a really long time to scroll through the whole page, you can write up a quick JavaScript program to do it for you, use a `while` loop to keep scrolling until hit the bottom (scroll position doesn't change any more) and inside the loop do something like `window.scrollBy(0, 3000);` to keep scrolling down.

Comment: on Mac  there is no End key

Comment: @FyodorGlebov There is no key, that's true. But if you Google it, you'll find that you can hold down the Fn key and press the right arrow key. That works just like the PC keyboard's end key (according to the site I looked at).

Answer (score 2):

You can just print the page to a pdf (Control + P on Windows, Command + P on Mac).

After pressing the shortcut, you should see something like this (depends on your browser):

[image: screenshot of the page after pressing the shortcut]

Change the dropdown to "Save to PDF" (again, depends on your browser).
[image]

Now it should let you choose where to save, and after that, you're good to go! However, it will not update as the site updates, so you can only access history at a certain point in time.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Facebook. It only prints the part of the page that is currently visible.